# How can I make the customer's email to show up on Invoice?

Tags: email, custom-options, invoice, customer-attribute, order-email

I was wondering how I could get a customer's email address to appear right underneath their Telephone number on an invoice in the "Sold to:" section.

The following is how the "Sold to:" section currently looks,

**John Doe

123 Fake Street

Beverly Hills, California, 90210

United States

T: (555) 555-5555**

and I want it to look like,

**John Doe

123 Fake Street

Beverly Hills, California, 90210

United States

T: (555) 555-5555

johndoe@johndoe.com**

**Edit:**
After some googling I stumbled upon this gem which worked for me just in case anyone else runs into the same issue.
[broken link]

Comment: You need this in invoice pdf

Comment: Do you know how I add it? I tried adding {{depend email}}{{var email}} {{/depend}} but that didn't work. I am not 100% sure that "email" is the correct variable. Can you elaborate on "You need this in invoice pdf"?

Comment: Regarding invoice there are many things,email,PDF where you need to add email after telephone

Comment: Do you know if that is the correct variable I add {{var email}}? Is it called something else because I tried what you suggested and that doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing I probably have the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to add the customer's email to invoice pdf as well as the email.

1) to add customer's email to invoice pdf.
open file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

find this line

`$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));`

and replace with

```
$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));
```

2) to add the customer's email to invoice email, change the below files

Change the function `sendEmail()` located in file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php`
Add `$email` in the template parameters.

```
$email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $order,
                'invoice'      => $this,
                'comment'      => $comment,
                'email'        => $email,
                'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );
```

Now you can access this variable like `{{var email}}` in the email template located in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html`

P.S. I will advice not to make changes in the core file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not considered best practise to edit core files in app/code/core as this is not update-safe so it would be better to rewrite these files and make your changes there. Maybe you'd like to update your question?

Comment: yes exactly, i mentioned in my answer too. wait let me edit my answer again

Comment: "replace with" code is exactly the same with "find this line" mentioned above !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the customer email in 'Sold to' in invoice PDF or order templates like this:

`{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}` or `Email: {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}`

In pdf you should replace this from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract::insertOrder

```
$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));
```

with

```
$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf').'|'.$order->getCustomerEmail());
```

Tested in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

**Reference:** Marius Answer [How do I add a customer's email to the sales invoice?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/how-do-i-add-a-customers-email-to-the-sales-invoice)