# Shipping section of Invoice pdf gets blank after adding customer email

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

Based on [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/how-do-i-add-a-customers-email-to-the-sales-invoice), to have the customer email address, I edited the `$shippingAddress` in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` like below, but it makes the shipping section in pdf show nothing. 
The customer is NOT LOGGED IN, does it matter? how to fix this?

```
$shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getShippingAddress()->format('pdf')).'|'.Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email:').$order->getCustomerEmail();
```

I'm wondering if `.'|'.Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email:').$order->getCustomerEmail();` is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getShippingAddress()->format('pdf'));
$billingAddress[] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email:').$order->getCustomerEmail();
```

**NB: Don't modify core code.**