# Display email address on the shipment page

Tags: magento-1.9

In the Shipment page, where you have the Billing Address and the Shipment Address, the management staff tells me she wants the email to show up there (rather complains that the email is not shown).

I am not sure about the page I have to edit whether it is the shipment page or something like

```
System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates
```

and while I code in PHP, I have no idea about Magento syntax so I dont know how to write those 4 or 5 words that would surely display it. For example, this shows address

```
 <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; 
      {{var order.billing_address.format('html')}}
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td valign="top" >


 {{var payment_html}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

My guess is that it would be something like this?

```
 {{var order.email_address.format('html')}}
```

But I don't know if it is

```
{{var order.email_address.format }}
```

or it should be just

```
{{var order.email.format('html')}}
```

UPDATE

On reading other posts
[How do I add a customer's email to the sales invoice?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/how-do-i-add-a-customers-email-to-the-sales-invoice)

it gives the instructions on how to write the code but it says:

You have to copy the file to the local folder. You cannot do a simple override because it's an abstract class.

Where is that the "local folder", where is the file I have to copy?

Comment: email id of customer or store ?

Comment: you could try `{{var order.customer_email}}` or `{{var customer.email}}`

Comment: I am not sure about that because I am reading this ..
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/how-do-i-add-a-customers-email-to-the-sales-invoice

Comment: @Arminius that post is for the customer's email

Comment: it is the customers email that I need to add , what other email address was I going to include?